# Какая разница между input type button и button?

Tags: html

Никак не могу понять какая разница между этими двумя тегами.И как правильно и где какой нужно использовать.?

Comment: Внутрь button можно пихать произвольный HTML-код а внутрь input не получится, вот и вся разница.

Comment: На всякий случай напомню, что [button тоже имеет атрибут type](https://webref.ru/html/button/type), который имеет значение по умолчанию submit, то есть работает как input type=submit

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Comment: если необходима стилизация кнопки - используйте button (работает с псевдоэлементами в отличии от input[type="button"])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле особо разницы никакой нет.

Тег button может иметь контент, его надо закрывать. 
Раньше его сторонились из-за старых версий IE, но это в прошлом:)

В некоторых браузерах для этих элементов могут различаться стандартные стили, хотя роль они выполняют одну и ту же